# Can not hook into CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn during MSBuild on my Web Application project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-web-deploy

My main goal is to add minified JS scripts to the deployment package of my ASP.NET web application **using `cmd`**.

Also my question may seem duplicate to [**this topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144472/how-can-we-include-the-files-created-by-ajaxmin-in-the-msdeploy-package-created) and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747081/how-do-you-include-additional-files-using-vs2010-web-deployment-packages/2748752#2748752) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137880/how-to-get-visual-studio-publish-functionality-to-include-files-from-post-buil/3145742#3145742), it's not the case.
My problem is that I've tried hooking into `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn`, `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn` and even `PipelineCollectFilesPhaseDependsOn` with no luck. I used `<Message Text="Inside of CustomCollectFiles" Importance="high"/>` inside my custom `Target` as **Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi** proposed [**in his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726052/msdeploy-package-has-missing-files/12375128#12375128) and `/v:diag` switch of `msbuild.exe` to verify this fact. I have no ideas how to fix it: tried to place corresponding XML snippet with different modifications from the questions above into `.csproj` file directly and also into a separate file `.wpp.targets` which is used to customize packaging.

My dev environment includes VS2010 and VS2013, I've installed Web Deployment 3.5 via Web PI, Web Deployment Tools, Windows Azure SDK. My system PATH environment var includes `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\;c:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3` to be able to run `MSBuild` and `MSDeploy` from `cmd`. When I look into the MSBuild log I see this:

```
CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn = 
  ;
  ;

CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn = 
  ;

  ;
;
```

some stuff goes here

```
PipelineDeployPhaseDependsOn = 
  ;
  Package;
```

So my question is where to find the source of my misfunctioning packaging pipeline?
What additional kind of diagnostics I missed out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that probably MSBuild cached build targets terribly wrong, but after **Windows restart** all kinds of hooking including the one from [this post which finally solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144472/how-can-we-include-the-files-created-by-ajaxmin-in-the-msdeploy-package-created) started to work as expected.

Also, for all who are doing automatic build stuff it might be interesting to note that web deplopy related stuff can be moved from the main `{Project Name}.csproj` file to the corresponding `{Project Name}.wpp.targets` file which I consider as a more elegant way of configuring build options especially if you don't want to include them in the TFS or want to customize build befaviour for different publish targets.

So, this is my final `.wpp.targets` file which works for me now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
        <IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>True</IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion>
        <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
        <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
        <AllowUntrustedCertificate>True</AllowUntrustedCertificate>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Building our Web Deploy package using Tools path $(VSToolsPath)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>

<!--  More verbose way of doing the same as with BeforeTargets -->
<!--  <PropertyGroup>-->
<!--    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>-->
<!--      CollectJsMinFiles;-->
<!--      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);-->
<!--    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>-->
<!--    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>-->
<!--      CollectJsMinFiles;-->
<!--      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn);-->
<!--    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>-->
<!--  </PropertyGroup>-->
<!--  <Target Name="CollectJsMinFiles"> -->

  <Target Name="CollectJsMinFiles" BeforeTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage;CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
    <Message Text="Collecting min JS files in CollectJsMinFiles" Importance="high"/>
    <ItemGroup>
      <JsMinFiles Include="**\*.min.js" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(JsMinFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```